# Iteration through 2d array in lua

Tags: lua, multidimensional-array

I'm starting some lua scripting and seem to be stuck at a simple problem.

I'm actually trying to implement a Floyd-Warschall algorithm to compute all the shortest paths between each vertices of a graph ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd–Warshall_algorithm for a short explanation of the algorithm). It is originally written in python (here's the code https://gist.github.com/DavidCain/4032399 ). My version is a little different, in order to make it fit my main code, but it is basically the same thing.

Here's my commented code. Every time I run it, I get a "attempt to index field '?' (A nil value)" (I feel the solution is simple enough, but I can't seem to put my finger on it. Any help would be appreciated):

```
function adj(bodies) --returns, from a 1d array of vertices called "bodies", a square adjacency matrix (a matrix of size number_of_vertices x number_of_vertices that tells, with a ones, if vertices are connected, or with 'infs' if they are not connected)
    n = table.getn(bodies)
    dist = {}
    for _,i in pairs(bodies) do
        dist[i] = {}
        for _,j in pairs(bodies) do
            if i == j then
                dist[i][j] = 0
            end
            if areConnected(i,j) == true then --areConnected is another function I wrote to see if, well, two particular vertices are actually connected. If they are, distance is 1, if not, distance is inf.
                dist[i][j] = 1
            else dist[i][j] = math.huge
            end
        end
    end
    return adjMatrix
end

function PhysicsDebugDraw:fw(adjMatrix) --I pass adjMatrix to this function

d = adjMatrix 

    for _,k in pairs(d) do
        for _,i in pairs(d) do
            for _,j in pairs(d) do
                d[i][j] = math.min(d[i][j], d[i][k] + d[k][j]) -- the problem is here I suspect...
            end
        end
    end
    return d
end
```

Comment: What *is* the problem you need help with? I haven't run your code, but by looking at it, I don't see anything wrong with table manipulation.

Comment: I get a "attempt to index field '?' (A nil value)" error. But if my code is right, there must be a problem elsewhere in my code...

Comment: Just add the full error + any stacktrace you get to your question please.

Comment: @Rodolphe I made some more edits to my answer. See if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not show the structure of `adjMatrix` or what its layout actually looks like but from looking at your triple nested loop, its usage is likely incorrect.

Note that variables `k`, `i` and `j` here:

```
for _,k in pairs(d) do
  for _,i in pairs(d) do
    for _,j in pairs(d) do
      d[i][j] = math.min(d[i][j], d[i][k] + d[k][j])
    end
  end
end
```

are *not* the keys of your `adjMatrix` but the value part of the pair. Remember `pairs` returns key follow by value on each iteration. But the inner most loop you're accessing `adjMatrix`'s content using *the value* as the key.

Without seeing the actual structure of `adjMatrix` it'll be hard to recommend a solution that correctly iterates over it. But making `k`, `i` and `j` hold the `key` part is a reasonable start.

```
for k in pairs(d) do
  for i in pairs(d) do
    for j in pairs(d) do
      d[i][j] = math.min(d[i][j], d[i][k] + d[k][j])
    end
  end
end
```

Note that if your `adjMatrix` uses numbers as keys and it's continuous(no numbers get skipped) you can just use `#adjMatrix` instead of `pairs(adjMatrix)`.

**Edit:** After looking at your python version, I made the following observations:

- `adj` returns a square-like matrix. That is its width == height
- "empty" cells are represented as infinity
- after conversion with `adj` the table's (or python dict) rows and columns are continuous
- `fw` makes a "shallow" copy of `g`

Assuming the above invariants are true(let me know if they're not) then the following would be a more faithful translation in lua:

```
function shallow_copy(g)
  local h = {}
  for k, v in pairs(g) do
    h[k] = v
    end
  return h
  end

--[[
eg.
g = {
        {0, 3, 8, math.huge, -4},
        {math.huge, 0, math.huge, 1, 7},
        {math.huge, 4, 0, math.huge, math.huge},
        {2, math.huge, -5, 0, math.huge},
        {math.huge, math.huge, math.huge, 6, 0},
    }
--]]
function fw(g)
  local d = shallow_copy(g)
  for k = 1, #d do
    for i = 1, #d do
      for j = 1, #d do
        d[i][j] = math.min(d[i][j], d[i][k] + d[k][j])
        end
        end
        end

  return d
  end
```

You may pretend that the `end` keyword is invisible. :P

Comment: cheers @Greatwolf, I updated my question with a few more details. I'm trying your code now.